# Run Python script from Laravel Controller

Tags: php, python, laravel-4

I want to run the python script from laravel. I'm using the PHP exec function to execute my command, but I'm not successful yet. There's a button in my view, on which I want to run the script.
Here's the code for button:

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'run_script','method' => 'get'))}}
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Run script</button>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('run_script',nameOfController@funcName);
```

In Controller:

```
exec('/usr/bin/python /path/to/folders/where/I/have/script/name_of_script.py' , $output, $return);

        if (!$return) 
        {
            throw \Exception('Error running script '.__FILE__);
            echo "python script run Successfully";

        } 

        else {
        echo "Failed :( </br>";
        }
        var_dump($output);
```

The vardump of $output gives me empty array with Failed message. 
I'm not sure either I'm doing it in a right way or not. I'm confused that either I should use "Get" method to run the script or not.

P.s please don't get upset with me I'm learning python and laravel, so my apologies If I'm doing it wrong all the way.

Comment: If it executes the script then everything is working because you enter the controller. so front to back end is ok. If this is the right way to do it is another question. But anyway are you sure the script is working? Can you post it?

Comment: @DavidMaes: Yes, I'm sure the script is working because I have run it manually through command lines

Comment: Can you please find out what value the variable $return holds. If the script ran successfully it should be '0' I guess. In php 0 is false. I do not understand why you throw an exception and echo the script ran successfully. But first lets find out what $result holds.

Comment: @DavidMaes $return = 1. Oops, looks like I'm echoing wrong statements. Am I? And the $output = array(0) {}. I'm not doing json decode in my python script, is it because I'm getting $output = array(0){}?

Comment: Return code 1 means there was an error/problem. Something went wrong. So do the check like this:
 
 if($return != 0){
  throw \Exception('Error running script '.__FILE__);
 }
 echo "python script run Successfully";

Comment: @DavidMaes After doing if($return != 0) I'm getting this error "Call to undefined function Exception()"

Comment: I just copied that from your code above. Just throw a new exception there. Also make sure the script has execution permissions for everybody. So throw new Exception ()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107560/discussion-between-david-maes-and-tayyaba-khalid).

Comment: @DavidMaes, noo, not the chat! If you found a solution, please post it as an answer so other poor chaps like myself can see figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @TayyabaKhalid, You too. If you remember what worked, please put it below.

Comment: @Naltroc: I didn't find any solutions